# Logic question related to file size check during implementation of aws file upload

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am implementing aws file upload, does aws provide a method to check the size of a file when it is uploaded? I am developing using springboot in java.
Thank you

I did a search related to aws, but it was difficult to find it by myself, so I had to post a question.

Comment: Why would you need to know the size of files? Spring projects are relatively small and take almost no space(excluding dependencies)

Comment: It's a small project I'm personally working on.
The implementation of uploading files to aws s3 has been completed.
However, when uploading, if the file size and format are checked and printed out, I thought it would be a more convenient function to include.
So I'm still looking for it,
harder than you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using aws sdk, you can get the size of the file in bytes by using the getSize() method in the `S3ObjectSummary` class after uploading the file.

See the [List Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#list-objects) doc or the Class [S3ObjectSummary](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectSummary.html) doc.

Or if you want to get the size of a file before uploading, access the file directly and get the size of the file.

```
File file = new File(path);
long length = file.length();
```

Comment: I was busy yesterday, so I didn't get a reply right away. Thanks for the great reply!! Let's take a look and implement it.

Comment: Great. If this answer was useful to you, please accept it :) @ladenbestizer

Comment: Thanks for making the implementation easy! thank you!!